# WPF, mouse position relative to display resolution?

Tags: wpf

What's the fastest way to get mouse position with respect to display resolution ??

Answer (score 0):

Relative to Form

```
Point p = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
```

Relative to some Control

```
Point p = Mouse.GetPosition(Label1);
```